# Creating a Single Row Calendar Layout in HTML, CSS, JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a project where I need to implement a single-row calendar layout, and I have a specific design in mind. I have an image that illustrates the desired result, and I'm struggling to figure out the best approach to achieve this.
[image: Below is result I want]
The image shows a calendar with a single row, displaying days horizontally. Each month has its corresponding days, and the layout spans across the screen horizontally. I'm using PHP, and I'm unsure about the best way to structure the HTML and CSS to achieve this responsive and visually appealing layout.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Or do you want people to just give you the answers?

Comment: how is that layout *responsive*? I won't ask about *visually appealing* as that is your subjective opinion - also, why have you tagged your question with `javascript` when you don't even mention javascript at all?

Comment: Please consider to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the stackoverflow `Help Center / asking`. You should at least include in your question what you have tried so far and where you got stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to share the solution I found for creating a single-row calendar using **Owl Carousel, Bootstrap, and jQuery.** After experimenting and combining these tools, I was able to achieve a functional and visually appealing calendar design. Here's the approach I took:

```js
const months = [
        "January",
        "February",
        "March",
        "April",
        "May",
        "June",
        "July",
        "August",
        "September",
        "October",
        "November",
        "December",
      ];
      chooseddate = "";
      const monthShortNames = months.map((month) => month.substring(0, 3));
      const calendarContainer = $("#calendar-container");
      const yearDropdown = $("#yearDropdown");
      const monthDropdown = $("#monthDropdown");

      function isTodayOrFuture(year, month, day) {
        const today = new Date();
        const dateToCheck = new Date(year, month, day);
        return dateToCheck >= today;
      }
      const currentYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      const currentMonth = new Date().getMonth();
      const currentDay = new Date().getDate();

      function updateMonthDropdownOptions(selectedYear) {
        const monthDropdown = $("#monthDropdown");
        monthDropdown.empty();

        for (let month = 0; month < 12; month++) {
          const daysInMonth = new Date(selectedYear, month + 1, 0).getDate();
          if (
            daysInMonth >= new Date().getDate() ||
            selectedYear > currentYear
          ) {
            const option = $("<option>").val(month).text(months[month]);
            monthDropdown.append(option);
          }
        }
        const defaultMonth =
          currentMonth < new Date(selectedYear, 0).getMonth()
            ? currentMonth
            : 0;
        monthDropdown.val(defaultMonth);
      }

      function updateCalendar(year, month) {
        calendarContainer.owlCarousel("destroy");
        calendarContainer.empty();
        calendarContainer.owlCarousel({
          loop: false,
          nav: true,
          navText: [
            '<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-left fa-fw"></i>',
            '<i class="fa-solid fa-chevron-right fa-fw"></i>',
          ],
          margin: 10,
          responsive: {
            0: {
              items: 1,
            },
            600: {
              items: 3,
            },
            1000: {
              items: 6,
            },
          },
          lazyLoad: true,
        });
        const daysInMonth = new Date(year, month + 1, 0).getDate();
        for (let day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
          const dateString = `${year}-${(month + 1)
            .toString()
            .padStart(2, "0")}-${day.toString().padStart(2, "0")}`;
          
          if (
            isTodayOrFuture(year, month, day) ||
            (year === currentYear &&
              month === currentMonth &&
              day === currentDay)
          ) {
            const dayCard = $("<div>")
              .addClass("day-card card rounded")
              .html(
                "<p class='fw-bold'>" +
                  getDayOfWeek(year, month, day) +
                  "</p>" +
                  "<h3>" +
                  day +
                  "</h3>" +
                  "<p>" +
                  monthShortNames[month] +
                  "</p>"
              )
              .css("cursor", "pointer")
              .data("date", dateString);

            dayCard.on("click", function () {
                calendarContainer
                  .find(".day-card")
                  .removeClass("border-success selectedcard");
                const clickedDate = $(this).data("date");
                console.log("Clicked on", clickedDate);
                chooseddate = clickedDate;
                $(this).addClass("border-success selectedcard");
            });
            calendarContainer.trigger("add.owl.carousel", [dayCard]);
          }
        }
        calendarContainer.trigger("refresh.owl.carousel");
      }
      yearDropdown.val(currentYear);
      updateMonthDropdownOptions(currentYear);
      updateCalendar(currentYear, currentMonth);

      yearDropdown.on("change", function () {
        const selectedYear = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        const selectedMonth = parseInt(monthDropdown.val(), 10);
        updateMonthDropdownOptions(selectedYear);
        updateCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth);
      });

      monthDropdown.on("change", function () {
        const selectedMonth = parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
        const selectedYear = parseInt(yearDropdown.val(), 10);
        updateCalendar(selectedYear, selectedMonth);
      });

      function getDayOfWeek(year, month, day) {
        const date = new Date(year, month, day);
        const daysOfWeek = [
          "Sunday",
          "Monday",
          "Tuesday",
          "Wednesday",
          "Thursday",
          "Friday",
          "Saturday",
        ];
        return daysOfWeek[date.getDay()];
      }
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.3.4/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.5.1/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-DTOQO9RWCH3ppGqcWaEA1BIZOC6xxalwEsw9c2QQeAIftl+Vegovlnee1c9QX4TctnWMn13TZye+giMm8e2LwA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer" />
<div class="row w-100 m-auto mb-1 text-center">
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="yearDropdown">
          <option value="">Select Year</option>
          <option value="2023" selected>2023</option>
          <option value="2024">2024</option>
          <option value="2025">2025</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 mb-2">
        <select class="form-control" id="monthDropdown">
          <option value="0">January</option>
          <option value="1">February</option>
          <option value="2">March</option>
          <option value="3">April</option>
          <option value="4">May</option>
          <option value="5">June</option>
          <option value="6">July</option>
          <option value="7">August</option>
          <option value="8">September</option>
          <option value="9">October</option>
          <option value="10">November</option>
          <option value="11">December</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12 mt-1">
        <div class="owl-carousel" id="calendar-container"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The HTML and CSS are fairly simple, obviously tweak to your exact needs.

```css
ol.calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  gap: 0.5em;
  li {
    flex: 0 0 7em;
    display: block;
    padding: 0.25em;
    border: solid #aaa 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    div {
      &:nth-child(1) {
        letter-spacing: -0.04em;
      }
      &:nth-child(2) {
        font-size: 2em;
        font-weight: 800;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<ol class="calendar">

  <li>
    <div>FRIDAY</div>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>SATURDAY</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>SUNDAY</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>MONDAY</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>TUESDAY</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>WEDNESDAY</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>THURSDAY</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>FRIDAY</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>SATURDAY</div>
    <div>9</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>SUNDAY</div>
    <div>10</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>MONDAY</div>
    <div>11</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

  <li>
    <div>TUESDAY</div>
    <div>12</div>
    <div>DEC</div>
  </li>

</ol>
```

To be honest, you wouldn't need to use `ol` and `li` either, they can all be `div` if you want - I use ol/li since semantically it is an ordered list with list items :p

Or, and since you've tagged `javascript` but haven't tagged `php`, here's some javascript to create the whole calendar - this time without `<ol>/<li>`

It's a little more convoluted than it needs to be, simply to allow multiple months :p

```js
function makeCalendar(year, month) {
  const frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
  const months = document.querySelector('.months');
  const month_template = document.querySelector('#month-template');
  const clone = month_template.content.cloneNode(true);
  frag.append(clone)
  const tgt = frag.firstElementChild;
  const template = document.querySelector('#day-template');
  const date = new Date(year, month - 1, 1);
  while(date.getMonth() === month - 1) {
    const parts = date
      .toLocaleDateString(undefined, {weekday:"long", month:"short", day:"numeric"})
      .split(/,? /)
      .map(s => s.toUpperCase());
    const clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    clone.querySelectorAll(".day > div").forEach((el, index) => el.textContent = parts[index]);
    tgt.appendChild(clone);
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
  }
  months.append(frag);
}
makeCalendar(2023, 11); // code takes one away from month
makeCalendar(2023, 12); // code takes one away from month
```

```css
.months .month {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 0.5em;
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding-block: 2em;
  .day {
    flex: 0 0 7em;
    padding: 0.25em;
    border: solid #aaa 1px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    text-align: center;
    .dow {
      letter-spacing: -0.04em;
    }
    .date {
      font-size: 2em;
      font-weight: 800;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="months">
</div>

<template id="month-template">
  <div class="month">
  </div>
</template>

<template id="day-template">
  <div class="day">
    <div class="dow"></div>
    <div class="date"></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here´s another one as a template to start with. The function gives you exact weekdays and daynumbers to a month:

```
<?php

function dates_month($month, $year)
{
    $num = cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $month, $year);
    $dates_month = array();

    for ($i = 1; $i <= $num; $i++) {
        $mktime = mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $i, $year);
        $dates_month[$i]['weekday'] = date("D", $mktime);
        $dates_month[$i]['day'] = date("d", $mktime);
        $dates_month[$i]['month'] = date("M", $mktime);
    }

    return $dates_month;
}

$currentRow = dates_month(12, 2023);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>

        .boxes {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row nowrap;
            justify-items: left;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            font-weight: bold;
        }

        .box {
            flex: 0 0 70px;
            border: 1px solid black;
            border-radius: 10px;
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            margin-right: 20px;
            text-align: center;
            height: 100px;
        }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="boxes">
        <?php
        foreach ($currentRow as $currentDay) {
        ?>
            <div class="box">
                <div class="weekday"><?= $currentDay['weekday']; ?></div>
                <div class="day"><?= $currentDay['day']; ?></div>
                <div class="month"><?= $currentDay['month']; ?></div>
            </div>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd give a `PHP` answer, since `php` isn't even tagged in the question :p (I'm just being pedantic though)

Comment: It´s Xmas, and he mentioned to use PHP. XD